# Django ORM for custom python function

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have following two models

```
class Membership(models.BaseModel):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    package = models.ForeignKey(Package, on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True, null=True, related_name="package_membersips")
    benefit_end = models.DateField()
    benefit_start = models.DateField()


class Package(models.BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)


class PackageTier(BaseModel):
    package = models.ForeignKey(Package, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='package_tiers')
    min_members = models.IntegerField()
    max_members = models.IntegerField()
    retail_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    wholesale_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
```

The `wholesale_price` and `retail_price` calculation consists of some logic, that is difficult to perform using ORM:

```
def get_package_price(package_instance):
    count = package_instance.package_memberships.count()
    tier = package_instance.package_tiers.filter(
        min_members__lte=count + 1,
        max_members__gte=count + 1
    ).first()
    if not tier:
        tier = package_instance.package_tiers.order_by('id').first()
    return tier.retail_price if tier else 0


def get_package_wholesale_price(package_instance):
    count = package_instance.package_memberships.count()
    tier = package_instance.package_tiers.filter(
        min_members__lte=count,
        max_members__gte=count
    ).first()
    if not tier:
        tier = package_instance.package_tiers.order_by('id').first()
    return tier.wholesale_price if tier else 0
```

These are business logic and I need to aggregate the result based on the year basis.

```
# sample response:
{"data": [
                {
                    
                    "year": 2021,
                    "commission": 1.0
                },
                {                    
                    "year": 2022,
                    "commission": 8.2                    
                },
                {
                     "year": 2023,
                     "commission": 11.0
                },
        ]}
```

Is there any way that I can use `get_package_price` and `get_package_wholesale_price` inside Django ORM ?

I used following ORM to get `membership` for each year:

```
Membership.objects.all().annotate(year=ExtractYear('benefit_start')).values('year').order_by('year')
```

The custom function need to be called in this ORM.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is a django model manager [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/managers/)

for example:

```
class PackageManager(models.Manager)
    def get_package_price(self, package_instance):
        # Get your price

class Package(models.Model):
    objects = PackageManager()
    # Rest of your model
```

and then you can call it by: `Package.objects.get_package_price(package_instance)`